# how to create an array of id image from assets have many folders

Tags: android, android-view

I have many folders and images in assets, example: "folder1/img1.jpg, img2.jpg...img15.jpg; folder2/img1.jpg, img2.jpg...img20.jpg;.....". I have a ListView with name of all folders in assets with AssetManager, when OnClickItem i will load all images from item clicked (selected folder). Because i use code "Curl Page" on GitHub, i need array of ID to load all images in each folder don't use simple array for drawable, example:

`private int[] mIdsSelectedFolder = { R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,... R.drawable.img15};`

then i load image:

`Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(mIdsSelectFolder[index]);`

But i don't know How to count numble image in each folder then get all ID image, create an array from each folder, don't input all resource by copy and paste image's name same example above, because each folder have number of images different!

Comment: flagged as `low quality`

Comment: +1 Good question. What you are trying to accomplish is clear from the code snippets and description.

Comment: Now for some questions: Why do you need an array of the resource IDs? Can you give a link to the "Curl Page" project you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the id by name using getIdentifier.

below you will see the sample code:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("img" + index , "id", getPackageName());
if (id!= null)
{
     Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create costume listview. and override getView method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.userprofilepic, null, true);

        ImageView img= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

        img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(mIdsSelectFolder[position]););



        return view;
    }
```

Comment: A little explaino will not hurt :)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will list out files resides in "directory".

```
try {
    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
    String str[] = getAssets().list("directory_name");
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        Log.d("TAG", str[i]);
        if (str[i].endsWith(".jpg")) {
            Drawable drw = Drawable.createFromStream(am.open(str[i]),null);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You just need to create array of particular **directory** and add file names inside that. You can also create custom class for that also. In my example, if file name ends with **JPG**, will take drawable from it.

**EDITED:** Drawable.createFomStream() to Drawable.createFromStream()